# When I do the following in vscode, it is a union of string and null, but for some reason it is only a string

Tags: typescript

When I do the following in vscode, it is a union of string and null, but for some reason it is only a string.

let foo: null | string;

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVXXY.png)

i want to know the cause

sorry for bothering you, but please tell me!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because that in the `tsconfig` file, `strictNullChecks` property is `false`. When it is `false` it makes all types like `number`, `string`, etc, more extended so that `null` and `undefined` types will be as a part of that type. So `string` type (that is shown by vscode) in `strictNullChecks = false` mode, is actually

```
string | null | undefined
```

But if you change `strictNullChecks` value to `true` you will see that vscode shows that just like

```
string | null
```

If the file you have mentioned is not part of an existing project and there is no `tsconfig` file that you could find, search for `Implicit Project Config: Strict Null Checks` in **vscode** settings and change that property.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! that was right, it help me a lot

Comment: thanks for the additional information, there is tsconfig in our project

Comment: I changed to strict: true, It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it is a special case in vscode and is marked as something like a nullable string. If you want to know exactly what happens, you can always read the vscode source code on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode).